# How to set Html Css text to TextView

Tags: css, textview, htmltext

I have Textview.am getting web response in the fallowing way

**asdgfsagasgs**
*asdsa sa sad asd sada sdas* 
*asdsad ad sad sad sad ad asdsad*
*asdsadsadsadsadsadsad*
*asdsadsadsadsaddsadsadasdasdasda sda asd* 
*sdasdsadasdsadsadsadasdasdads*

- sadasdsadasddsad
- *asdsadsadas sad sad sad asd*
- *sadasdas sad sadsaas sad*
- *asdas sa sa asd sad asd asd asd asd*

1. *asddsadsadasdasd*
2. *asddsadsadasdasdasddsadsadasdasd*
3. *asddsadsadasdasd*
4. *asddsadsadasdasdas ddsadsadasdasdasddsa dsadasdasdasddsadsadasdasd*
5. *asddsadsadasdasdasddsadsadasdasd*

> *asdasdsadsadads*

how can i set to layout for apply span style color and every thing.

Comment: Clarify Your Question with a fiddle Pls !

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to set textview style to bold and italic**

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);      // for Normal Text
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);      // for Italic
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); // for Bold and Italic
```

**You can use this to change style of specific word as:**

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + Year: + "</b>"+"2012,
                  "+"<b>" + Language: + "</b>"+":Armenian,"
                  "+"<b>" + Subtitles: + "</b>"+":English"));
```

Also You can go for `SpannableString` for Creating an String with different fonts,colors or style.

`SpannableString(CharSequence source)`